# Exception 'yii\base\UnknownPropertyException' in migrate/up

Tags: yii, yii2, migration, database-migration, yii2-advanced-app

I want to use [yii2-forms extension](https://packagist.org/packages/pceuropa/yii2-forms) but I have problem in migration.

here is the error during migration.

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\SEPreport>yii migrate/up --migrationPath=@vendor/pceuropa/yii2-forms/migrations
Exception 'yii\base\UnknownPropertyException' with message 'Setting unknown property: yii\console\Request::enableCsrfValidation'

in C:\xampp\htdocs\SEPreport\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Component.php:209

Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\SEPreport\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\BaseYii.php(546): yii\base\Component->__set('enableCsrfValid...', false)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\SEPreport\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\BaseObject.php(107): yii\BaseYii::configure(Object(yii\console\Request), Array)
#2 [internal function]: yii\base\BaseObject->__construct(Array)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\SEPreport\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php(383): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\SEPreport\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php(156): yii\di\Container->build('yii\\console\\Req...', Array, Array)
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\SEPreport\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\BaseYii.php(349): yii\di\Container->get('yii\\console\\Req...', Array, Array)
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\SEPreport\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\ServiceLocator.php(137): yii\BaseYii::createObject(Array)
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\SEPreport\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(742): yii\di\ServiceLocator->get('request', true)
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\SEPreport\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\console\Application.php(219): yii\base\Module->get('request')
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\SEPreport\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(386): yii\console\Application->getRequest()
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\SEPreport\yii(27): yii\base\Application->run()
#11 {main}
```

and also I set `enableCsrfValidation` in **frontend** and **backend**:

```
'components' => [
        'request' => [
            'enableCsrfValidation' => false, // I set it to true too
            'enableCookieValidation' => false,
        ],
]
```

please help me. what do I have to do for solve it?

Comment: You should not set `enableCsrfValidation` settings in console or common config - it should be in frontend and/or backend config.

Comment: @rob006 I did it before, But did'nt work

Comment: @rob006 I updated my qustion. plz check it. do you mean set `enableCsrfValidation` like this?

Comment: Do you have any config for `request` component in `common` or `console` config?

Comment: yes I had in `console` now I removed it. and it works, let me check rest of it.

Comment: @rob006 its works. you can put it as a answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may get such errors if you put web-specific settings in `console` or `common` config files. Console `Request` does not have `enableCsrfValidation` property, so `yii\base\UnknownPropertyException` exception is thrown.

If you want to configure web-specific setting you should do this in `backend/config/main.php` and/or `frontend/config/main.php`.